# .webpart file EmptyMessage Property changes not reflecting

Tags: sharepoint

we are facing an issue where a custom webpart is alreay deployed in sharepoint and when we are trying to update its EmptyMessage Property and redeploying it, its not reflecting in UI,however, we can see the .webpart file has updated with new value. here is the code snippet of .webpart file

```
 <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="EmptyMessage" type="string">Currently there are no features available. Please check back.</property>
    <property name="ShowBestBets" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ShowViewDuplicates" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">False</property>
```

We're using ctx.ClientControl.get_emptyMessage() to read this property value.

Comment: When you check in the web part gallery of an existing site, does it still contain the old .webpart file? That would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. It does contain updated values, and when i readd the webpart to a new page, i can see new values. The only issue there is its not updating this property values for existing pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

*[filename].webpart* is just a template for web part instances in the pages. Existing pages save their web part parameters once the web parts are added in the pages. Web part properties in a particular page have no link back to the *.webpart* file.